# Android Mobile Vision text recognition zoom to found coordinates

Tags: android, zooming, touchimageview

I'm using Googles Mobile Vision API to recognize text (numbers) in a static Bitmap. Now I would like to zoom in to the place where the number was found.

So this is how I scan the Bitmap and obtain my x and y coordinates

> Point[] p = textBlock.getCornerPoints();

```
public void Test(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    TextRecognizer ocrFrame = new TextRecognizer.Builder(context).build();
    Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = frame.getGrayscaleImageData();

    if (ocrFrame.isOperational()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Textrecognizer is operational");
    }
    SparseArray<TextBlock> textBlocks = ocrFrame.detect(frame);

    for (int i = 0; i < textBlocks.size(); i++) {
        TextBlock textBlock = textBlocks.get(textBlocks.keyAt(i));
        String value = textBlock.getValue();
        Point[] p = textBlock.getCornerPoints();
        Log.e(TAG, "something is happening");
    }
}
```

Furthermore, I´m using the TouchImageView to display the bitmap. Now I'm calling the setZoom method with my obtained coordinates like this:

> touchImageView.setZoom(1F, 210F, 748F, ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);

But it zooms to the wrong place and I don't really know why. Can anybody give me some tips?

(https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/TouchImageView.java)

EDIT: Ok, I figured it out that scale type does something I don't get. The problem here is setZoom, I think. I have to convert the coordinates of the bitmap to the coordinates of the Touchimageview.

EDIT2: Solution: Mistake was to pass the x and y coordinate directly but setZoom take values between 0 and 1

```
int BitmapHeight = photo.getHeight();
int BitmapWidth = photo.getWidth();

int FoundX = p[0].x;
int FoundY = p[0].y;

float DividerX = BitmapWidth / (float)FoundX;
float DividerY = BitmapHeight / (float)FoundY;

float ZoomX = 1 / (float)DividerX;
float ZoomY = 1 / (float)DividerY;

touchImageView.setZoom(touchImageView.getMaxZoom(), ZoomX, ZoomY, ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
```

Comment: solved your issue ?

Comment: yes look at my edit 2

Answer (score 0):

You can use this google library https://developers.google.com/vision/android/text-overview .
You can find example here https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mobile-vision-ocr

by adding below in android gradle file

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.0'
```

Comment: I’m using this library.